# VS2008 Smart Device Class Library Project Template

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compact-framework

I was trying to create a new Class Library project targeted for the .NET Compact Framework.

However, when I select **"New project -> Smart Device"** I only have the **Smart Device Project** template.

I've checked the folder:
**C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\SmartDevice\1033**
It contains several project templates:

- SmartDeviceClassLibrary
- SmartDeviceConsoleApplication
- SmartDeviceEmptyProject
- SmartDeviceWindowsApplication
- SmartDeviceWindowsControlLibrary

None of those are shown on my IDE.
How can I use one of those project templates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct, you should only have one available.  Select it and click OK and you'll get the "Add New Smart Device Project" wizard that will *then* show you all of the types (Class Library, Device Application, etc) to choose from.

Comment: Thank you so very much. You're absolutely correct! I've completely forgot about the wizard and was having a bad time trying to do this stuff... It must be the "end-of-the-week" syndrome ;-)